# How to click this Frame Name in selenium c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frame

So I have this code right now in c# winforms using Firefox Selenium.

I need to click on a frame with the name

```
fancybox-frame1593883548
```

and inside frame i need to click this item by id

```
 id=webtraffic_popup_start_button
```

just one problem is the frame changes random Numbers all the time

```
fancybox-frame[1691838348](Never the same inside [])
```

I've tried this in c#

```
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame("fancybox-frame*");
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='webtraffic_popup_start_button']")).Click();
```

as you can tell i need to click the webtraffic button inside this frame.
Error was couldn't find fancybox-frame*

Thanks for help.

Here is the HTML Code of the frame if you need it

```
<iframe id="fancybox-frame1419019998476" name="fancybox-frame1419019998476" class="fancybox-    iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="auto" src="https://live.hyprmx.com/embedded_videos/player?uid=489861&amp;site=LootPalace&amp;distributorid=3827666&amp;rewards[][max_quantity]=29&amp;rewards[][reward_id]=0&amp;rewards[][title]=PlunderPoints&amp;rewards[][value_in_dollars]=0.0028"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the element (frame) properly before switching to that element.

Try this

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'fancybox-frame')]")));
```

Comment: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //iframe[contains(@name,'fancybox-frame'] because of the following error:

SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: No it is three ')'. It just breaks when i run it saying the above error

Comment: Sorry ..there was a typo.. I have edited the answer. Or Try this.

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'fancybox-frame')]")));

Answer (score 0):

Try with classname and cssSelector

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='fancybox-    iframe']")));
```

or, using xpath

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'fancybox-frame')]")));
```

If that's the only IFrame on the page you can alternatively do:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

or `driver.switchTo().frame(index)` 
if more than one iframe exist on the page